# Excess of data when reading file in MatLab

Tags: matlab

faced with the problem, txt file have 1000 double values, but when I have loaded this file, I get 2000, other values are zero values.
Help me please, I just started learning Matlab.

```
clear all
file = 'C:\data.txt';
x = load(file);
x = sort(x(:));

x

x =  1.0e+010 *

0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
...
```

Comment: Try using `fprintf`?

Comment: You should not use the `load` function - which is more for loading binary mat files - but `dlmread` or `textscan` to read text data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Matlab function textscan. This function goes line by line and parses data into C as a cell array. You can also control the number of lines it reads in based on the number N.

```
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N)
```

The [Matlab website has many examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0kfn) on how to call this function.

Comment: You should probably give some insight as to what `fileID`, `formatSpec` and `N` are for self-containment.  Only refer people to links as a reference as you don't know when that link will expire.  StackOverflow answers are designed to be self-contained.